# Link two cells so that edits to either are reflected

Tags: vba, excel

I have two cells, "R3" and "S3", in the same Excel sheet, "Data", which I want to link so that a manual entry to either is reflected across to the other with a correcting factor. Circular references prevent using formulae. I searched here and found this VBA snippet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    If target.Address = "$R$3" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("$S$3").Value = target.Value*2.55
    End If
End Sub
```

It was originally meant to link two cells on different sheets and in my own case the cells are on the same sheet. This works perfectly for entering in one and seeing the change in the other in one direction only. I can also add additional cell pairs using ElseIf. However, if I expand it to contain a dual reference as in R3->S3 and S3->R3 like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    If target.Address = "$R$3" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("$S$3").Value = target.Value*2.55
    Else If target.Address = "$S$3" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("$R$3").Value = target.Value/2.55
    End If
End Sub
```

Even though the two sections seem mutually exclusive and cannot both be referenced in the same procedure call, this crashes my spreadsheet every time I try to make a change. Obviously I am doing something hugely wrong! I had been led to believe from the original post that this would not cause a circular reference.

My guess is that I should be approaching this with two separate procedures, or is it just plain impossible based on this code?

Comment: As Tom stated below, you can use `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = True` to stop the loop.  In fact, you can put it directly into your `Worksheet_Change` subroutine, although I tend to agree with Tom, that breaking it out is better.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an infinite loop using the change module. By updating one it triggers the event using the other cell

update your change event to look like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Or Target.Address = "$B$1" Then
        Call cellUpdate(Target.Address)
    End If
End Sub
```

and then in a module put:

```
Sub cellUpdate(Target As String)
Application.EnableEvents = False
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
        If Target = "$R$3" Then
            .Range("$S$3").Value = .Range(Target) * 2.55
        ElseIf Target = "$S$3" Then
            .Range("$R$3").Value = .Range(Target) / 2.55
        End If
    End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

By breaking it out into a separate module and controlling the `Application.EnableEvents` in the separate module you stop the infinite loop.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing one `End If`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$R$3" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("$S$3").Value = Target.Value * 2.55
Else
    If Target.Address = "$S$3" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("$R$3").Value = Target.Value / 2.55
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I assumed this was a typo and the op meant `elseif` as they are looking at two specific cells. Also this still creates the infinite loop - One updates the other triggering the other to update the first.

Comment: I tried it before I posted it, and it doesn't create infinite loop, it updates only if target address was changed (R3/S3) by user, which then update cell R3/S3. SheetChange event doesn't consider this as change and does not run in loop.

Comment: What version of excel are you on? Either way you don't need two `if` statements - you could just use `if` and `elseif` to get what you've answered with

Comment: I'm using Office 2013 Pro. Yes, code is not perfect, i just edited OP's code to get result he requested

Comment: ok I'm on 2007 so this could be why we're getting different results. Your edit added 6 characters compared to removing 1 bloating and slowing down your code (probably not important in this example but could be important in larger projects)

Comment: Thanks Tom and user2250595. First apologies, it was a typo, I meant to type ElseIf so there was no missing EndIf.  My mental auto correction kicked in and my thumb hit the space key without me meaning to.  I've set things up to use Workbook_SheetChange() but for some reason nothing happens.

Comment: (Should have added Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010)