# Allow two cells to depend on each other

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula that allows me to calculate a formula that has two variables.  I want to be able to enter either variable A and have it calculate B, OR enter variable B and have it calculate A.

Formula to calculate my variables:

- Value = NOI / CAP
- CAP = NOI / Value
- Value is in cell A1
- NOI is in cell A2
- CAP is in cell A3

NOI is a known value.  I want to have separate cells for Value and CAP, and be able to enter data into either cell and have the other cell compute based on my data entry.

I was going to try an `IF` function with an `ISBLANK`, but I'm not sure how to do this that won't overwrite the formula.

Comment: You can have a formula or enter a value, but you can't do both.  The workaround is to use the `Worksheet_change` event to monitor each of the two cells and set the other one according to any entered value.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33298874/link-two-cells-so-that-edits-to-either-are-reflected

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking. @TimWilliams probably has the right idea, but based on the title of your question, you might also be looking for [circular references](https://chandoo.org/wp/excel-circular-references/) (which are hard to get right but sometimes useful).

Answer (score 5):

You can have a formula, or enter a value, but you can't do both. The workaround is to use the `Worksheet_change` event to monitor each of the two cells and set the other one according to any entered value.

This would go in the worksheet code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Goto haveError:

    If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Me.Range("A3").Value = 'set value in A3
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    If Target.Address = "$A$3" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Me.Range("A2").Value = 'set value in A3
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    Exit sub

haveError:
    'make sure events are re-enabled if an error occurs
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate approach you can enter the number in cell A1.  In Cell A2 State if it is Cap or Value.  In Cell A3 place your NOI.  Since the formula is essentially the same for both cases you can simply use the following in A4:

```
=A3/A1
```

In B4 I would place the following to indicate which value it was:

```
=IF(A2="Value", "CAP", IF(A2="CAP","Value", "Enter Type in A2"))
```

However if you absolutely want data entry in A1 or A2 and then have the other cell get calculated then your only approach is VBA as Tim Williams has pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this without macros using the ISFORMULA() function, which is available in Excel 2013 or later.  The trick is ISFORMULA() can query the state of a cell without actually evaluating it's value, and so can be used to direct a formula to avoid referring to that cell and causing a circular reference.

To wit:

A1 is Value, A2 is NOI (which is given) and A3 is CAP

```
A1: =IF(NOT(ISFORMULA(A3)), A2 / A3, "")
A2: 123.456
A3: =IF(NOT(ISFORMULA(A1)), A2 / A1, "")
```

Both A1 and A3 will remain blank until you enter a value in either one of them, at which time the other will be calculated appropriately.